# How do you find and replace a word/phrase in excel using C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am currently creating a program for staff members to auto populate and print out a check sheet with information based on user input etc. The check sheet is created as an excel document and I want to search the document for a particular word or phrase and replace that with the variable input the user generates.

Example: User inputs room number RM:XXX and the program will the search the document for phrase {Room Number} and replace it with RM:XXX. I found some solutions that did not work with Visual Basic 2017.

The closest solution I came to building a resolution from was:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application replaceWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = default(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook);

 wb = replaceWord.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xlsx");

 wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace(What: "{Room Number}", Replacement: "RM:XXX", LookAt: XlLookAt.xlWhole, SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: true, ReplaceFormat: false);
```

The issue was on the last line wb.Worksheets came up with an error: {"non-invocable member WorkBook.Worksheets cannot be used like a member."}

Can anyone point me in the right direction to where I can find out why wb.Worksheets is not working or throwing an error?

Comment: Worksheets sound like a collection `wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"]`

Comment: Isn't the command wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace(What:="{Room Number}", ... I think you are missing the =

Comment: @frostbyte = would be an invalid expression term if placed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.worksheets.aspx) is an property, not an method. That is what the error message is trying to tell you.

The property gives you an [Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.aspx) instance that implements an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.item.aspx) and in C# those are accessed by using `[]`. Your last line should look like this:

```
wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"]
  .Cells
  .Replace(What: "{Room Number}", 
           Replacement: "RM:XXX", 
           LookAt: XlLookAt.xlWhole, 
           SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, 
           MatchCase: false,  
           SearchFormat: true, 
           ReplaceFormat: false);
```

Notice the square brackets at `Worksheets["Sheet1"]`. Those make a difference.